# How to make a gradient continue in other divs

Tags: css

I would like my gradient to pass on to the next div. Putting one div behind them with the gradient would probably work, but on my website the elements are not exactly next to eachother

```css
.row {
  clear: both;
}

.portrait {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.photo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portrait">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/chingwai/pen/poEGxBe

To explain my structure:

`.portrait` = is the container, this is dynamically created based on my database.

`.photo` = will be a profile photo

`.gradient` = This is where the gradient should come and continue to the other divs that contain `.gradient` As you can see `.photo` will be between the divs, so they are not postioned under eachother.

[image]

Comment: now its my question as well.

Comment: Is the display flexible? those Divs might change places?

Comment: @Eldshe the divs are dynamic. This depends on the amount of data I have in my database. So if I have for example 6 people in it, it will create 6 divs

Comment: Is the image is the expected result?

Comment: @ATP, no, between DIV1-4 2-5 and 3-6 there is a photo

Comment: Can you add code to your question? Give us a couple examples since you are saying that the `divs` may not be next to each other.

Comment: @disinfor sure, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. It seems it's a bit different than what your image is trying to show. Can you update the stack snippet so it's a bit clearer what elements are what?

Comment: @disinfor Sorry, I created the image thinking it would be quicker and easier, but I think it caused more confusion. I have added comments to try to explain what I mean

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give all the divs you want to be with the gradient BG:

```
     background-image: linear-gradient(your choice);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
```

```css
.child{
height:120px;
width:120px;
border:solid 2px white;


background-image: linear-gradient(to right,pink,green);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.parent{
display:flex;
width: 250px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

After your explanations on the comments and post edits. Do this:

```
.gradient{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, blue, lightblue);
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted :D